# How to start up bind9 server

Tags: bind, knoppix

I tried everything to start bind9 server and I finally found this> run named -g

I do not know what else to do.

```
root@Microknoppix:/home/knoppix# named -g
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 starting BIND 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u2-Debian (Extended Support Version) <id:998753c>
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 running on Linux i686 5.3.5 #17 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 23 17:54:30 CEST 2019
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 built with '--build=i686-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu' '--libexecdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--with-python=python3' '--localstatedir=/' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-gost=no' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-libidn2' '--with-libjson=/usr' '--with-lmdb=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--with-atf=no' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-rrl' '--enable-filter-aaaa' '--enable-native-pkcs11' '--with-pkcs11=/usr/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so' '--with-randomdev=/dev/urandom' '--enable-dnstap' 'build_alias=i686-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/bind9-q3FpOH/bind9-9.11.5.P4+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -DNO_VERSION_DATE -DDIG_SIGCHASE' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 running as: named -g
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 compiled by GCC 8.3.0
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 compiled with OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 linked to OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 compiled with libxml2 version: 2.9.4
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 linked to libxml2 version: 20904
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 compiled with libjson-c version: 0.12.1
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 linked to libjson-c version: 0.12.1
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 threads support is enabled
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 ----------------------------------------------------
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit 
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are 
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 available at https://www.isc.org/support
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 ----------------------------------------------------
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 adjusted limit on open files from 500000 to 1048576
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 found 4 CPUs, using 4 worker threads
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.743 using 3 UDP listeners per interface
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.744 using up to 4096 sockets
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.748 loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.748 /etc/bind/named.conf:9: open: /etc/bind/named.conf.options: file not found
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.748 loading configuration: file not found
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.748 exiting (due to fatal error)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.748 loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf' 
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.748 /etc/bind/named.conf:9: open: /etc/bind/named.conf.options: file not found 
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.748 loading configuration: file not found 
06-Oct-2020 20:34:13.748 exiting (due to fatal error)
```

It appears that your `/etc/bind/named.conf` references `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` but that `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` does not exist.